# how to delete parent row in mysql?

Tags: mysql, yii2, row, parent, sql-delete

I want to delete my row of table but it is parent row so i should delete child row for first. My question is how i can find child row and delete them and at last delete parent row?

I have 2 table have relation with **example.table** (my main table that have parent row) that have **id** column (my primary key). So how I can find that 2 table through **id** (in my main table) and delete child row?

I am using mysql database and yii2 framework.

Comment: Check my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51232338/how-i-can-find-specific-id-from-specific-table-in-all-tables-and-delete-all-rows/51232573#51232573). Is it applicable for you...?

Comment: if you have defined relations and using innoDb with foreign key constraints for `on delete` and `on update` you don't have to worry about finding the children as the models if generated via GII have the relations defined and using active record model to delete the parent will delete the children too,if you have parent in one table and children in the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can either manually find the children and delete them on your PHP script or use ON DELETE CASCADE on your foreign key definition

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html